# GPO app distribution only for x64 but not on XP

Tags: 64-bit, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

How can I define GPO on Windows Server to distribute an x64 application only to x64 machines, but not on XP 64?

I've tried to define a WMI filter:

```
root\CIMV2: Select * from Win32_Processor where AddressWidth = "64"
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want 64-bit machines that are newer than XP (Vista+), you can filter on the start of the Windows version number, since XP was v5.x and Vista through 8.1 are v6.x, and Windows 10 is 10.x)

Here's one that will filter Windows Vista through Windows 10 machines that are 64-bit:

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where (OSArchitecture like "64%" and (Version like "6.%" or Version like "10.%"))
```